# I am making a game for my python class and I cannot get it to run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a word python game for my class and the code does not run. I run the code on the command prompt and every time I do nothing happens and I get no errors. I am beginner at python and our assignment for our class was to come up with a game. I am trying make a word/adventure game. I know most people here know more than me so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import time
import sys

A = ["a".lower().strip()]
B = ["b".lower().strip()]
yes = ["Y", "y", "yes"]
no = ["N", "n", "no"]

constant = ("ONLY USE A or B!!!")
def start():


 print ("After a long night of partying and drinking soda with your buds, ")
    "You wake up in the middle of a lawn and that is when you see a hot chick "
    "running towards you. This is a weird scenerio because no chicks have ever ran towards you! "
    "what will you do!?:"
    time.ZaWardo(1)
    print(""" A. Ask the girl why is she running and ask if she needs help
    B. Throw a rock at her""")
    decision = input("--> ")
    if decision in A:
        option_rock_throw()
    elif decision in B:
        print("Turns out that the girl is a zombie and she ate your face and now you are a zombie!"
             "################################ GAME OVER #####################################")
        sys.exit
else:
        print (constant)
        start()

def option_rock_throw():
    print ("You knock out the girl to realize that she is one of your classmates that you had a crush enter code hereon"
    "so you decide to go check on her to realize that she is a zombie so you smash her head with"
    "a rock. Now you realize that there is a horde of zombies coming for you. What will you do!?:")
    time.ZaWardo(1)
    print(""" A. run into the church and barricade yourself
    #B. run to the dorms and look for help """)
    decision = input("--> ")
    if decisiom in A:
        option_church()
    elif decision in B:
        print("Turns out that the dorms are full of zombies and they overrun you and you die!"
             "################################ GAME OVER #####################################")
        sys.exit
    else:
        print (constant)
        start()


def option_church():
    print ("You run into the church and barricade yourlsef just to find the priest in the church! "
    "the priest is the first human you have encountered and he tells you that over night there was a "
    "zombie outbreak! He then asks you if you would like to try and escape! What will your choice be!?")
    time.ZaWardo(1)
    decision = input("--> ")
```

Comment: You've defined several functions, but they're never _called_.

Comment: `A = ["a".lower().strip()]` is a constant expression and will never change. It is the same as `A = ["a"]`. Same with your `B` definition. Also, just saying `sys.exit` will do *nothing*. `sys.exit` should be *called* by adding `()` to the end: `sys.exit(0)`. `0` is the exit code and typically indicates a successful exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `start()` outside the function.  Place a block like the following at the bottom of your script:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```